# Does Odata support "not in" operator?

Tags: api, odata

I am trying to use `not in` operator in odata.
So does it support or not?

If yes then could you please give some example.

I was going through this post and trying but could not success.
https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1478

Comment: The linked issue claims that `not(property in ('v1', 'v2'))` works

Answer (score 10):

> the comments in the linked git hub issue https://github.com/OData/odata.net/issues/1478 ***actually** demonstrates that there **are** variations of support **for** NOT IN*, even though there is not a single operator for it.

The .Net implementation of OData v4 does support the [IN Operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/in-operator) for arrays of discreetly defined values, it does not Support a `NOT-IN` style operator but it does have support for both `NOT` and `IN`.

`NOT` simply negates the expression result but we can also replicate the `NOT` functionality by equating the expression result with `false`.

I can't find a publicly available sample to share, but my local projects do not have any trouble with the following queries:

## IN

*Although redundant, the second query demonstrates that the result of `IN` is a boolean expression and that you can further chain that expression with further conditions.*

```
    ~/OData/Facilities?$filter=Entity/Title in ('Abbotsford','test')
    ~/OData/Facilities?$filter=Entity/Title in ('Abbotsford','test') eq true
```

returns:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:16486/odata/$metadata#Facilities(FacilityType,Id,Entity(Title))",
    "value": [
        {
            "FacilityType": "None",
            "Id": 1081,
            "Entity": {
                "Title": "Abbotsford"
            }
        },
        {
            "FacilityType": "None",
            "Id": 2009,
            "Entity": {
                "Title": "test"
            }
        },
        {
            "FacilityType": "None",
            "Id": 8046,
            "Entity": {
                "Title": "test"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

## NOT IN

```
~/OData/Facilities?$filter=not(Entity/Title in ('Abbotsford','test'))
~/OData/Facilities?$filter=Entity/Title in ('Abbotsford','test') eq false
```

```
{
    "@odata.context": "http://localhost:16486/odata/$metadata#Facilities(FacilityType,Id,Entity(Title))",
    "value": [
        {
            "FacilityType": "None",
            "Id": 1065,
            "Entity": {
                "Title": "Sleepy Hollow Templestowe Lower"
            }
        },
        {
            "FacilityType": "None",
            "Id": 13076,
            "Entity": {
                "Title": "Peach Meadows"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

---

If you model has addressable collection or array